# Accumulation points of trigonometric sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

I am interested if the following sequences have accumulation points:

$$x_{n} = \sin(2+\frac{1}{n})$$ and $$x_n = \tan (n)$$

Specifically for the first sequence is $1$ and $-1$ accumulation points? What do you think? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: The first series converges to $\sin 2$. For the second I don't see how to tackle it.

Answer (score 1):

As it was posted in a comment, the first converges to $\sin(2)$.

For the second, since $\pi$ is irrational, the set $\{ n+m \pi |m,n \in \mathbb N \}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How exactly does this observation influence the existence of accumulation points for the sequence?

Comment: @JohnJack A convergent sequence only has one accumulation point. As for the second, if you understand what dense means, that answers your question..

Comment: I understand that it means that every point in $\mathbb{R}$ is in the closure of that given set but how does this connect with the sequence that I gave?

Comment: Remember that $\tan$ is periodic with period $\pi$, so you are looking at the numbers 1, 2, 3, $4-\pi$, $5-\pi$, and so on. Because the ratio $1:\pi$ is irrational this ends up giving a set of points which is dense in the interval $[0,\pi]$. In other words, the sequence gets arbitrarily close to every point of the interval.

Comment: @almagest Could please you explain what you mean when you say "Because the ratio $1: \pi$ is irrational this ends up giving a set of point which is dense in the interval $[0, \pi]$?

Comment: Think of marking off points around a circle with radius 1/2, so the circumference is length $\pi$. Take any point, then move a distance $m\pi/n$ along the circumference and mark another point. Repeat. After a while you will get back to the original point, so you will only ever mark $n$ points. But if you go a distance 1 that is not true. You never return to the original point. You can also show (although it is not trivial) that the complete set of points is "dense" in the circumference.

Comment: Of course, all you have to do to answer the question is to find a single accumulation point. So suppose you start with the point 0 on the circumference. You need to show that by going far enough you get a point arbitrarily close to 0 in the circumference.

Comment: @almagest But you have only dealt with the domain of $\tan$ as defined by sequence as being dense in $[0,\pi]$, what about the actual values of the sequence? Does it follow from your reasoning and additionally by the facts that $\tan$ is increasing and continuous on intervals of $[0,\pi]$ that every point in $\mathbb{R}$ can be considered an accumulation point?

Comment: Well, provided you stick to a finite range $[-k,k]$ for the values of the sequence it is fairly obvious that their values will be dense too. But unless you are allowed to assume the result about being dense, it is easier just to prove that a particular point is an accumulation point of the sequence.